# Using three-phase transformer in reverse

Tags: transformer, three-phase

I'm in the US and installing a 45 kVA 480 V/208 V transformer in reverse, to power an electric car charger that requires 480 V. The secondary of the transformer is in wye configuration and I will be connecting that to my building 208 V three-phase.

Questions:

1. Should I connect the neutral of the transformer to building neutral?
2. The transformer will be adjacent to the main breaker panel. Can I connect a grounding wire from the transformer and my downstream 480 V connector to the ground in the breaker panel, or do I need to create a local grounding using buried copper rod or similar device?
3. I've seen references to connecting one leg of the output 480 V (from the delta output of the transformer) to ground. Is this necessary? It intuitively doesn't seem like a safe thing to do.

Comment: Seriously, this is not a DIY project.  First of all anywhere in the USA you will need a building permit.  To get a permit you must have plans.  To get plans you have to know what you are going to do.  Get a professional electrician who is experienced in these matter to take care of this for you.

Comment: If you have 208, then you have a 480 feed - why bother with this transformer at all? Waste of energy converting voltages needlessly.

Comment: " I've seen references to connecting one leg of the output 480 (from the delta output of the transformer) to ground.", you are contradicting yourself: "The secondary of the transformer is in wye configuration"

Comment: @rdtsc "If you have 208, then you have a 480 feed " That makes no sense.

Comment: what kind of in and out, what kind of xfmr... delta-delta delta-wye etc ?

Comment: "I've seen references to connecting one leg of the output 480 V (from the delta output of the transformer) to ground."  you could with a delta, not sure for what benefit.. [see here](https://ctlsys.com/support/corner-grounded_delta_circuits/)

Comment: see first comment. if you're asking, get a professional

Comment: The National Electrical Code (NEC) is the basis for the electrical codes of all jurisdictions in the US, but local codes have additional requirements that supplement NEC and sometimes supersede parts of NEC. The relevant parts of NEC are those that describe the requirements for "separately derived systems. Various aspects of the connected load may influence what should be done. You probably need advice from a local electrician and the manufacturer of the connected equipment. Check the instructions for the equipment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about the use (installation) of a product and about performing work in conformance with local electrical codes. This is not primarily a matter of electrical engineering design or theory.

Comment: This question would be a better fit over on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions), although installing 45kVA transformers isn't really a 'DIY' job...

Comment: @Marco, I read it as "the secondary (which will now become the primary) is in wye configuration ....". OP is reversing the transformer.

Comment: 1) I am using a contractor to do the work but installing transforers such as this in reverse is not anything he has experience with. So looking for answers to some of the details. 2) there is no accessible 480 feed to the building. 208v is coming out of the meter. 3) transformer is delta (480), wye (208). Right now the plan is to bond the transformer to the GND strip in the breaker panel, not use the neutral line on the wye, and not tie any part of the 480v output to GND (fully isolated). Plans have not been sent to the building dept for approval, the next step. Thank you for your comments.